# latex file opens to be empty

Tags: neovim, plugin-ultisnips

I am just starting to learn vim and im using neovim to write latex files. I open an existing file as follows:

```
nvim Personal Notes.tex
```

And the output for this is a blank nvim file. Is this not the way to open existing files? As per online guides, this is how you open a file but it doesn't seem to work. What could be the issue?

Also it would be nice if someone has any videos/document suggestions to learn nvim.

EDIT: I should also mention that even after adding snippets to Ulti-Snips, the shortcuts arent working in a blank document either.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Are you doing something to escape or quote the space in the filename? What OS?

Comment: Looks like the problem might be the space in the filename. Try adding quotes around it, either `nvim 'Personal Notes.tex'` or `nvim "Personal Notes.tex"`

Comment: @Heptite im not adding anything for space. Im using Mac OS Catalina. I tried filbranden suggestion of adding space and it gives the same empty file. I also tried using a file without any space and its the same empty output

Comment: @filbranden tried all the things in the above comment but no luck

Comment: Do i have to specific the path for the folder in which the file is located in?

Comment: You only have to specify the path if your current directory (do `pwd`) doesn't match the file path of the .tex file. (I assumed the file that exists really does have some text in it? I would try opening it in another the program to be sure...)

Comment: Okay, please try the following: use `nvim "Personal Notes.tex"` (note, filename is most likely case sensitive, just in case it should be rather `personal notes.tex` or similar. From nvim, type `2<C-g>`, that outputs the complete path of the currently opened file. Check this against a terminal if this matches, or try to use `:e Pers` and type `<C-D>` or `<Tab>` to have the filename autocompleted (using `<Tab>`) or show all available files (using `<C-D>`)

Comment: RE: learning, I recommend (roughly in this order) `vimtutor`, `:help`, and http://vimcasts.org and/or the author's book "Practical Vim"